# Remove invalid row from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I've table with inline create (when user click on new button it create new empty row **first** in the table, which he can put data inside),when user click on save I go to the controller and check if this values are valid,if yes store them on the DB.if not I raise exception to the UI and not store the data.The problem is that the new row is not stored but I see it in the UI. just when I refresh  the page in the browser the line was omitted..

My question is if there is a way by code search for the first line of the table and remove it explicitly from the UI?

I try like the following but its not refresh the table,any idea?

```
$("table:first").find("tr:first").remove();
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle replicating the problem? There is not enough here for us to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work with a general table.

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br />
<br />

<input type="submit" id="btnAdd" value="add"></input>
<input type="submit" id="btnRemove" value="remove"></input>
```

**jquery**

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
        $("table:first > tbody").prepend('<tr><td>new row</td></tr>');
    });

    $("#btnRemove").click(function () {
        $("table:first tr:first-child").remove();
    });
});
```

---

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5NxL4/